# OpenStack: launch instance with raw disk format

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have some headache with my OpenStack. What i'm trying to do is to create instance which disk is in RAW format instead of default qcow.

My disk image from which I'm trying to create the instance is in raw format too. I've created the image via:

```
openstack image create --public --disk-format raw --container-format bare --file CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1710.raw CentOS_7_raw
```

But when I launch instance from it I see that the disk is converted to Qcow2(v3) format.

Is there any possibility to run an instance with raw format disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upload image to glance:

   ```
   # openstack image create --public --disk-format raw --container-format bare --file CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1710.raw CentOS_7_raw
   +------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
   | Field            | Value                                                |
   +------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
   | checksum         | 9d9cf225d36976b25eba247cb5f85d89                     |
   | container_format | bare                                                 |
   | created_at       | 2017-11-13T20:27:39Z                                 |
   | disk_format      | raw                                                  |
   | file             | /v2/images/8a18ee68-1d9e-4a2a-8277-ff29035d7011/file |
   | id               | 8a18ee68-1d9e-4a2a-8277-ff29035d7011                 |
   | min_disk         | 0                                                    |
   | min_ram          | 0                                                    |
   | name             | CentOS_7_raw                                         |
   | owner            | 253f0c717bba45f8adf5c530b7194069                     |
   | protected        | False                                                |
   | schema           | /v2/schemas/image                                    |
   | size             | 8589934592                                           |
   | status           | active                                               |
   | tags             |                                                      |
   | updated_at       | 2017-11-13T20:28:01Z                                 |
   | virtual_size     | None                                                 |
   | visibility       | public                                               |
   +------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
   ```
2. Change `/etc/nova/nova.conf`. Update `images_type` parameter to `raw`:

   ```
   # VM Images format. If default is specified, then use_cow_images flag is used
   # instead of this one. (string value)
   # Allowed values: raw, qcow2, lvm, rbd, ploop, default
   #images_type=default
   images_type=raw
   ```
3. Restart nova:

   ```
   # openstack-service restart nova
   # openstack-service status nova
   MainPID=1485 Id=openstack-nova-api.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1500 Id=openstack-nova-cert.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1509 Id=openstack-nova-compute.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1483 Id=openstack-nova-conductor.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1525 Id=openstack-nova-consoleauth.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1481 Id=openstack-nova-novncproxy.service ActiveState=active
   MainPID=1511 Id=openstack-nova-scheduler.service ActiveState=active
   ```
4. Create instance:

   ```
   # nova boot --image 8a18ee68-1d9e-4a2a-8277-ff29035d7011 --nic net-id=e6db9b9e-4782-44dc-8d99-6bdb9744793d --key openstack --config-drive=True --flavor 3 raw
   +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
   | Property                             | Value                                               |
   +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
   | OS-DCF:diskConfig                    | MANUAL                                              |
   | OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone          |                                                     |
   | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                 | -                                                   |
   | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname  | -                                                   |
   | OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name        | instance-00000558                                   |
   | OS-EXT-STS:power_state               | 0                                                   |
   | OS-EXT-STS:task_state                | scheduling                                          |
   | OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                  | building                                            |
   | OS-SRV-USG:launched_at               | -                                                   |
   | OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at             | -                                                   |
   | accessIPv4                           |                                                     |
   | accessIPv6                           |                                                     |
   | adminPass                            | CTXhRYZv8bc3                                        |
   | config_drive                         | True                                                |
   | created                              | 2017-11-13T20:36:15Z                                |
   | flavor                               | m1.medium (3)                                       |
   | hostId                               |                                                     |
   | id                                   | 0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2                |
   | image                                | CentOS_7_raw (8a18ee68-1d9e-4a2a-8277-ff29035d7011) |
   | key_name                             | openstack                                           |
   | metadata                             | {}                                                  |
   | name                                 | raw                                                 |
   | os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached | []                                                  |
   | progress                             | 0                                                   |
   | security_groups                      | default                                             |
   | status                               | BUILD                                               |
   | tenant_id                            | 253f0c717bba45f8adf5c530b7194069                    |
   | updated                              | 2017-11-13T20:36:15Z                                |
   | user_id                              | f8a7f21341624657b81c882431966265                    |
   +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
   ```
5. Check status:

   ```
   # nova list
   +--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+
   | ID                                   | Name | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                |
   +--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+
   | 0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2 | raw  | ACTIVE | -          | Running     | network-1=192.168.0.139 |
   +--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------+
   ```
6. Check image file:

   ```
   # qemu-img info /var/lib/nova/instances/0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2/disk 
   image: /var/lib/nova/instances/0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2/disk
   file format: raw
   virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)
   disk size: 8.0G

   # ls -alh /var/lib/nova/instances/0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2/disk
   -rw-r--r--. 1 qemu qemu 40G Nov 13 20:51 /var/lib/nova/instances/0d7aaf0a-0b29-4c6e-b049-270beab7d9c2/disk
   ```